# Can I have composite constraints?

Tags: sql-server, constraints

Having a table with this structure...

Table_files

- id_file (PK)
- file_name
- file_path

... can I have a constraint that allows me to not duplicate the pair "file_name"+"file_path" (but allows me to duplicate the "file_name" and "file_path" individually), where the only Primary Key is the field "id_file"?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Create an index for the two fields, and make it unique.

Answer (score 2):

to go with what [Guffa said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565718/can-i-have-composite-constraints/1565748#1565748), create a unique index on the two fields:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table_files_name_path ON Table_files 
(
    file_name,file_path
)
GO
```

this prevents any combination of `file_name+file_path` from being duplicated, but allows for repeated values within `file_name` and `file_path` values, just not the same combination.